# How to perform a left join of list of dates with an existing table

Tags: mysql

I have a table which contains two columns: date, and revenues generated in this date, however, if no revenues were generated at a certain date, this date will not show in the table, what I want is to show this date with 0 as revenue.

I tried a query that generates a list of dates between two dates, however, I couldn't find how to left join this query with my table since this date generator query has no id.

this is my table query:

```
SELECT CAST(insertDate AS DATE) AS DATE, 
        SUM(timeofcall)*10 as total_Revenue_Generated_from_CallBacks
FROM callcompletion.tbl_calltracking
GROUP BY CAST(insertDate AS DATE);
```

results->

```
DATE          total_Revenue_Generated_from_CallBacks

2019-10-14    2200 
2019-10-15    44000
2019-10-16    4400
2019-10-17    8800
2019-10-24    12100
```

and this is the date generator query:

```
SELECT selected_date FROM (
    SELECT adddate('1970-01-01',t4.i*10000 + t3.i*1000 + t2.i*100 + t1.i*10 + t0.i) selected_date 
    from            
        (SELECT 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t0,
        (SELECT 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t1,
        (SELECT 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t2,
        (SELECT 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t3,
        (SELECT 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t4
) v
WHERE selected_date BETWEEN '2019-10-14' AND '2019-10-24'
```

results->

```
selected_date

2019-10-14
2019-10-15
2019-10-16
2019-10-17
2019-10-18
2019-10-19
2019-10-20
2019-10-21
2019-10-22
2019-10-23
2019-10-24
```

expected results:

```
DATE         total_Revenue_Generated_from_CallBacks

2019-10-14    2200    
2019-10-15    44000
2019-10-16    4400
2019-10-17    8800
2019-10-18    0
2019-10-19    0
2019-10-20    0
2019-10-21    0
2019-10-22    0
2019-10-23    0
2019-10-24    12100
```

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to decide what is the minimum and maximum date you wish to show. In addition to that, you can simply join the generated dates with your original query:

```
SELECT d.selected_date AS DATE, ifnull(SUM(c.timeofcall)*10,0) as total_Revenue_Generated_from_CallBacks
FROM (
  SELECT adddate('1970-01-01',t4.i*10000 + t3.i*1000 + t2.i*100 + t1.i*10 + t0.i) selected_date 
  FROM            
    (SELECT 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t0,
    (SELECT 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t1,
    (SELECT 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t2,
    (SELECT 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t3,
    (SELECT 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t4
) as d
  left join callcompletion.tbl_calltracking c on CAST(c.insertDate AS DATE) = d.selected_date
WHERE d.selected_date between '2019-10-14' and '2019-10-24'
GROUP BY d.selected_date;
```

See [DB-Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/P6szx89GHKtuaEQtN8fbR/1)

Comment: thank you for taking the time to answer, but for some reason, it did not work / i've put  START_DATE as '2019-10-14' and END_DATE as '2019-10-24'

Comment: Was written without testing. Should work now as the column name is now correct and the ifnull added. Btw, your date generation subquery might be bit heavy as it generates lot of dates (from 1970-01-01 to 2243-10-16).

Comment: The reference to your database (callcompletion) was missing. You can try again. If you still have problem, please post the error you are getting.